# how to secure login form in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, security, authentication, web, react-router

I have a small piece of code using React and React router, like:

```
<Route path='/' render={({location}) => (
    loggedIn ? (
        <ProtectedContent/>
    ) : (
        <Login/>
    )
)}/>
```

My question is when its minified and deployed, may be any attacker can play with the modified code and change that `loggedIn` with `true` and bypass the form, is there a way to secure it?

Edit: I know that only client side javascript can be attacked, I am asking about the solutions for this like for example node application that handle login and if user logged in then serve the `ProtectedContent` bundle, or make 2 JS bundles and serve them through nodejs...etc

Comment: How do you set the loggedIn variable and which authentication scheme are you using?

Comment: ha ha. This cannot be prevented. But i think, the data shown in protected content should be served from a server that is secured. The UI is always vulnerable

Comment: @Swapnil the loggedIn variable is set when there is success login in the form, its set through actions and get from redux store, and I think the authentication scheme is irrelevant here, no?

Comment: @Panther you mean through react server side rendering for example?

Comment: If the content is protected, then it should not be served in first place until you know for sure you are logged in. So what i would do is `ProtectedContent` would be a dummy holder and the actual content will be fetched from the server via a ajax call. The ajax request should have necessary authentication details(like token) for the server to determine if the content can be served. When the ajax succeeds, then populate the data in the component. I would not load all the protectedcontent before knowing the user is logged in or not